# Access Request values in Jmeter Post processors

Tags: jmeter

Is there any function for accessing the Jmeter request values since my response after creation list all data in database i want to filter out with specific created value using JSON path extractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to post some JSON and want to apply JSON Extractor to this data it can be done in 2 steps:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following piece of code in order to save request data into `request` JMeter Variable:

   ```
   vars.put('request', sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   ```

   where:

   - `vars` - shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
   - `sampler` - shorthand for the current [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the JSR223 PreProcessor's scope

   see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information and examples
2. Once done you can use JSON Extractor and point it to the `request` JMeter Variable

   [image]

Demo:

[image]